# UUID warning when npm installing Love.js

Tags: node.js, npm, lua, uuid, love2d

I am trying to install Love.js using npm on Windows, but when I do I am met with a warning about the UUID being the wrong version. After using
npm -v uuid, it displays that it is on version 8.3.0, which is not what the [warning shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjPRl.png).

Although this is just a warning, Love.js is unable to run on this version. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling node.js, npm, pm2 and uuid with no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `npm -v` returns the npm version and not the package version of UUID. What node version are u using?

Comment: I am using v16.13.1